# Auto click a link by class name using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to auto click a link using a class name instead of the ID name.

however my approach doesn't do anything!

Here is what I have done:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   document.getElementsByClassName("some-iclass").click();
});
</script>
```

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

EDIT:

I've used the following code and still doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".myLink").click();
});
</script>

<a class="myLink" href="http://yahoo.com"> CLICK HERE NOW </a>
```

and I have this right at the top of my page header:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

EIDT:

i've tried this as well and still doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myLink').trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you cannot click it because you have not defined click method for the link tag .

Comment: Most likely, no click event is bound to the link. It **IS** clickable however, if there's a href in there it will follow that link.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

here you go:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.className').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

hope that helps.

**UPDATE:**

try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    window.location.href = $('.className').attr('href');
});
</script>
```

after your edit, i think this is what you need.

Comment: I've tried using your code and it didn't work! could you please provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: This did it mate. Great. appreciate it.

Comment: one more question, how can I use the same method to auto click on an image like this: `<img class="close" src="images/closey.gif" style="display: inline;"></img>`  ?

Comment: Thank you very much it helped.

Answer (score 10):

`getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an element but a NodeList which may contain more than one element.

You may do this :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("some-iclass")[0].click();
```

or if you want to click all elements :

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("some-iclass");
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) list[i].click();
```

But as you use jQuery, it would be simpler to do

```
$('.some-iclass').click();
```

but only when the click event handler was added with jQuery (in other cases, like for example in case of an href attribute, use the standard dom functions).

Comment: +1 for the `$('.some-iclass').click();` due to compatibility with older browsers, e.g. ie7+

Comment: could you please provide a working jsfiddle as I cannot get this to work!

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xEEF/). Your tests with Yahoo.com can't work because Yahoo doesn't want to be embedded in a frame (cross origin settings).

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".some-iclass").trigger('click');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple with jquery `$(".some-iclass").click();`

if you have a lot of elements with this class - point to the wanted element:
i.e.  `$($(".some-iclass")[0]).click();`

Answer (score 2):

for auto-clicking a button or a link

"<"body onload="document.getElementById('some-class')[0].click()" ">"

this works...:)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to autoclick a link and you are using jQuery, you could use

```
$('.yourClass').click();
```

if you need this to be one link in a collection of multiple links, you could do this:

```
$($('.yourClass')[0]).click();
```

Where 0 is the index of the element in the jQuery object.

`document.getElementsByClassName('yourClass');` does not work in older browsers so it's best to use jQuery here for cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I managed to make it work that way. I deployed the automatic click in 5000 milliseconds and then closed the loop after 1000 milliseconds. Then there was only 1 automatic click.

```
<script> 
var myVar = setInterval(function ({document.getElementById("test").click();}, 500); 
setInterval(function () {clearInterval(myVar)}, 1000); 
</script>
```